# No appenders could be found for logger when calling Java class from Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, log4j

My class uses log4j for logging, but when I call this class from Matlab, the following warning occurs:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.mycompany.MyClass).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I was trying to place `log4j.properties` in various location, including root of JAR file, some directory of class path, but this didn't helped.

What is general approach of configuring log4j under Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

```
The “log4j: WARN. . .” is due to a bug in the MATLAB and Simulink Report Generators.
```

The bug was fixed for R2012a where an error message is thrown to inform you that there was a Java out of memory error.

As a workaround you can increase the Java heap space for MATLAB. You can find the Java heap space setting in the MATLAB Preferences under

*File -> Preferences -> General -> Java Heap Space.*

Comment: I am using `2016b` and heap is 16g